# Is there evidence to suggest that receiving angry emails increases stress levels?

Tags: emotion, communication, stress

There are plenty of [helpful descriptions](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/all-the-rage/201302/avoiding-the-angry-email-0) of how to avoid angry emails. The [reasoning](https://hbr.org/2014/02/the-best-way-to-defuse-your-stress) is largely that it doesn't solve the problem. That is, sending an email whilst angry causes more problems for you than it solves.

But what about the recipient? Logically and analytically we know that people don't respond well to an emotive email. But is there statistical or experimental evidence of the changes in brain/body state (or behaviour) that occur when people receive emotive emails?

My question is: **Is there evidence to suggest that receiving angry emails increases stress levels?**

Comment: Well there's evidence to indicate that receiving emails at all can increase stress. And there's evidence that being at the end of someone's anger is stressful. But I'm having a difficult time finding work specifically towards angry emails and stress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reaction to an angry email is just the same as reacting to any angry comment (verbal or written). It is usually seen as a provocation and triggers the urge to retaliate or invoke self-defense. The mental stress is a consequence of this situation. Often this stress is transient.

I have no nowledge of any documented evidence of stress or the level and duration of the same.

Comment: References to stress levels as a result of provocation would be appreciated. (: